# EF3 core in-memory database OrderBy "sequence contains no elements" exception

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

This works fine when connected to SQL but throws an exception when using the In Memory Database

`Actors` collection gets initialized to `new List<Actor>` in `Movie` constructor.

```
public class Actor
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        Actors = new List<Actor>();
    }

    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}

var searchQuery = context.Movies.Where(m => m.Name == "Jaws");
searchQuery = searchQuery.OrderBy(m => m.Actors.Min(a => a.BirthDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue));
```

Comment: can you show your entities?

Comment: @GabrielLlorico updated

Comment: why do you need to `initialize` in the constructor `Actors = new List<Actor>()`?

Comment: So that it's not null

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, remove `Actor = new List<Actor>` in constructor

```
public Movie()
{
}
```

in your query `.Include(m => m.Actor)`

```
var searchQuery = context.Movies.Include(m => m.Actors).Where(m => m.Name == "Jaws");
```